# Random Forest variable Importance Z Score

Tags: random-forest

I am really worried How does RandomForest Algorithm Works internally,

1. Out of bag error
2. Variable Importance
3. Z Scores

Let me know all these three ? How to calculate it? What it controls?

Answer (score 4):

Please allow me to cite the [site](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ebreiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm) of creators of the `RandomForest` algorithm

Out of bag error

> In random forests, there is no need for cross-validation or a separate test set to get an unbiased estimate of the test set error. It is estimated internally, during the run, as follows:
>
> Each tree is constructed using a different bootstrap sample from the original data. About one-third of the cases are left out of the bootstrap sample and not used in the construction of the kth tree.
>
> Put each case left out in the construction of the kth tree down the kth tree to get a classification. In this way, a test set classification is obtained for each case in about one-third of the trees. At the end of the run, take j to be the class that got most of the votes every time case n was oob. The proportion of times that j is not equal to the true class of n averaged over all cases is the **oob error estimate**. This has proven to be unbiased in many tests.

Variable importance and Z-score

> In every tree grown in the forest, put down the oob cases and count the number of votes cast for the correct class. Now randomly permute the values of variable m in the oob cases and put these cases down the tree. Subtract the number of votes for the correct class in the variable-m-permuted oob data from the number of votes for the correct class in the untouched oob data. The average of this number over all trees in the forest is the **raw importance score** for variable m.
>
> If the values of this score from tree to tree are independent, then the standard error can be computed by a standard computation. The correlations of these scores between trees have been computed for a number of data sets and proved to be quite low, therefore we compute standard errors in the classical way, divide the raw score by its standard error to get a z-score, ands assign a significance level to the **z-score** assuming normality.